# Migrate existing Squarespace site to AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, web, migration, content-management-system, squarespace

I have I Squarespace website I made for myself a while back. The main purpose at the time was to have something to link to from my iOS app, and I opted for something expedient rather that thinking long term just to get the app released. Fast forward to now and I have an AWS EC2 instance where I could do more with a personal site in the future. Ultimately it would be nice to get it off Squarespace and not have to pay another full year billing cycle, but the renewal date is a pretty tight deadline at this point.

Nothing on this domain requires must more than frontend web code really, but a completely different page UI could take more time than I have for this. I'm wondering if there might be a way to just temporarily have the Squarespace page source as is running on EC2 so I can worry about a possible non CMS design when I'm not worried about getting billed for another whole year by Squarespace.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but if not it seems like I should just port the content to minimalistic empty html files with no styling just to avoid the billing or get billed for a shorter time period. Billing seems like the limiting factor here. I would also need to add my new credit card to get billed for more time which I also have yet to do.

Basically, has anyone else dealt with this situation personally? What would you recommend I do? Does Squarespace even allow me to port to EC2 somehow, or is that more in the realm of WordPress? Thanks.

**Note:** Tomcat's what I'm using on the EC2 instance currently. I will also need to do the multiple site per instance setup for this, but I believe that's the most relevant config info here unless I'm forgetting something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you've already chosen to use Tomcat as I don't see anything that would allow you to easily convert your Squarespace site to a Java webapp. It looks like Squarespace sites [can be exported into Wordpress](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206566687-Exporting-your-site), which you could host on an EC2 server.

Alternatively you could use `wget` to create a static copy of your website which you could then host easily on your EC2 server with [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/), or skip EC2 and just host the [static website on S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html).